js file working in local environment but not working in browser environment
I have a js file that will take submitted data from a form and send it to my gmail. I wrote the JS code and executed the file using node in git bash, and it sends the email correctly with the following result:
Received request: POST /formSubmition.js
Handling POST request
    `Submitted data: {
    year: [ 'Year' ],
    make: [ 'Make' ],
    model: [ 'Model' ],
    trim: [ 'Trim' ],
    mileage: [ '' ],
    name: [ 'test' ],
    email: [ 'test70@gmail.com' ],
    phone: [ '1234567' ],
    province: [ 'Province' ],
    message: [ 'test' ]
    }`
Sending email...
Email sent: 250 2.0.0 OK  1717798919 ffacd0b85a97d-35f0e989bc9sm932675f8f.54 - gsmtp

I then hosted the file in funio via cpanel and open the website on the internet. I fill the form and submit it, a post request is made to the file correctly but nothing is sent.
nodemon starting node file
Server is running on port 3000

This is the result in putty, and when I submit the form it doesn't change, as if it didn't receive any request although the request was made. The same code is used in both files.
I am using putty after connecting with an ssh key to open the terminal and execute the file and i execute the local file using git bash.
I used the same nodemon version but it didn't work. I also used pm2, didn't work. Changed ports, changed some of the code, but still didn't work. I tried to change node version but didn't work.
I use putty to execute the hosted file and use git bash to execute the local file.
    const http = require('http');
    const fs = require('fs');
    const formidable = require('formidable');
    const crypto = require('crypto');
    const nodemailer = require('nodemailer');
    const config = require('./config');
    const selectionMappings = {
        //mapping here
    };
    
    function decryptData(encryptedData, secretKey, iv) {
        try {
            const decipher = crypto.createDecipheriv('aes-256-cbc', Buffer.from(secretKey, 'hex'),    Buffer.from(iv, 'hex'));
            let decryptedData = decipher.update(encryptedData, 'hex', 'utf-8');
            decryptedData += decipher.final('utf-8');
            return decryptedData;
        } catch (error) {
            console.error('Error decrypting data:', error);
            return null;
        }
    }
    
    const decryptedPassword = decryptData(config.gmail.encryptedPassword, config.gmail.secretKey,  config.gmail.iv);
    
    if (decryptedPassword !== null) {
        console.log('Decrypted password:', decryptedPassword);
    
        const transporter = nodemailer.createTransport({
            service: 'gmail',
            auth: {
                user: config.gmail.username,
                pass: decryptedPassword,
            },
         });
    
        const MAX_ATTACHMENT_SIZE_LIMIT = 25 * 1024 * 1024;
    
        async function sendEmail(submittedData, files, senderEmail, res) {
            console.log('Sending email...');
            const mailOptions = {
                from: senderEmail,
                to: 'alias@gmail.com', //enter your gmail
                subject: 'Submitted Form Data',
                text: JSON.stringify(submittedData),
                attachments: []
            };
    
            const attachments = [];
            for (const file of Object.values(files)) {
                try {
                    const content = await fs.promises.readFile(file.path);
                    attachments.push({
                        filename: file.name,
                        content: content,
                        contentType: getContentType(file.type)
                    });
                } catch (error) {
                    console.error('Error reading file:', error);
                }
            }
    
            const totalAttachmentSize = attachments.reduce((total, attachment) => total +        attachment.content.length, 0);
    
            if (totalAttachmentSize <= MAX_ATTACHMENT_SIZE_LIMIT) {
                mailOptions.attachments = attachments;
             } else {
                console.error('Attachments exceed size limit. Email will be sent without attachments.');
            }

            try {
                const info = await transporter.sendMail(mailOptions);
                console.log('Email sent:', info.response);
                // Send thank you page content as the response
                 fs.readFile(__dirname + '/submitted.html', 'utf8', (err, content) => {
                    if (err) {
                        console.error('Error reading thank you HTML file:', err);
                        res.writeHead(500, { 'Content-Type': 'text/plain' });
                        res.end('Internal Server Error');
                    } else {
                        res.writeHead(200, { 'Content-Type': 'text/html' });
                        res.end(content);
                    }
                });
            } catch (error) {
                console.error('Error sending email:', error);
                // Send alert to user if email sending fails
                res.writeHead(500, { 'Content-Type': 'text/plain' });
                res.end('Error sending email');
            }
        }
    
        function getContentType(fileType) {
            switch (fileType) {
                case 'image/jpeg':
                    return 'image/jpeg';
                case 'image/png':
                    return 'image/png';
                case 'application/pdf':
                    return 'application/pdf';
                default:
                    return 'application/octet-stream';
            }
        }
    
        const server = http.createServer((req, res) => {
            console.log('Received request:', req.method, req.url);
    
            // Access control headers
            res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*');
            res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'POST, GET, OPTIONS'); // Include GET method
            res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', 'Content-Type');
    
            if (req.method === 'OPTIONS') {
                console.log('Handling OPTIONS request');
                res.writeHead(200);
                res.end();
                return;
            }
    
            if (req.method === 'GET' && req.url === '/submitted.html') {
                console.log('Handling GET request for /submitted.html');
                // Send thank you page content as the response
                fs.readFile(__dirname + '/submitted.html', 'utf8', (err, content) => {
                    if (err) {
                        console.error('Error reading thank you HTML file:', err);
                        res.writeHead(500, { 'Content-Type': 'text/plain' });
                        res.end('Internal Server Error');
                    } else {
                        res.writeHead(200, { 'Content-Type': 'text/html' });
                        res.end(content);
                    }
                });
            } else if (req.method === 'POST') {
                console.log('Handling POST request');
                const form = new formidable.IncomingForm();
    
                form.parse(req, (err, fields, files) => {
                    if (err) {
                        console.error('Error parsing form data:', err);
                        res.writeHead(500, { 'Content-Type': 'text/plain' });
                        res.end('Internal Server Error');
                        return;
                    }
    
                    const senderEmail = fields.senderEmail;
    
                    Object.entries(fields).forEach(([key, value]) => {
                        if (selectionMappings[key] && selectionMappings[key][value]) {
                            fields[key] = selectionMappings[key][value];
                        }
                    });

                    console.log('Submitted data:', fields);

                    const formData = { ...fields, files };
    
                    sendEmail(formData, files, senderEmail, res);
                });
            } else {
                console.error('Unsupported method:', req.method);
                res.writeHead(405, { 'Content-Type': 'text/plain' });
                res.end('Error: Only POST method is allowed for form submission.');
            }
        });
    
        const PORT = process.env.PORT || 3000;
        server.listen(PORT, () => {
            console.log(`Server is running on port ${PORT}`);
        });
    } else {
        console.error('Decryption failed. Check decryption parameters and encrypted data.');
    }

